# rows to CSV with extra characters

Tags: excel

I have the task of creating a simple Excel sheet that takes an unspecified number of rows in Column A like this:

```
1-10-13
1-12-3
1-15-13
```

And make them into a comma-separated list in another cell that the user can easily copy and paste into another program like so:

```
1-10-13,1-12-3,1-15-13
```

This can be done by and draging down:

```
=B1&","&A2
```

However, I need the output to be like such:

```
GIS_ID in ('WV-1-10-13', 'WV-51-1-12-3', 'WV-1-15-13')
```

Basically, I need to prepend the whole thing with `GIS_ID in (` and then insert `WV-` before each value AND put each in single `''` quotes. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this need to be an Excel formula?

Comment: yes why do you ask?

Comment: Because VBA could be a good solution otherwise. No need as you have an answer below.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A1** through **A3**, use:

```
="GIS_ID in ('WV-" & TEXTJOIN("', 'WV-",TRUE,A1:A3) & "')"
```

[image]

The formula can easily be expanded to handle more than three cells.